# Install sas Viya in OCP/kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, sas

Install sas Viya in OCP/kubernetes [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) or any shared kubernetes cluster.

By looking at [Cluster Requirements for Red Hat OpenShift](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/itopscdc/v_040/itopssr/n098rczq46ffjfn1xbgfzahytnmx.htm#n0lrj1a1ia0fg9n1kxjlsedfg4dy) I cannot find any details if Sas Viya can be installed on a shared OCP cluster on a specific namespace/project (I assume does because OCP/kubernetes is to hold multiple apps and not a single app but not sure about this product since is not providing details or diagram around it).

I do assume that SAS Viya is an app that does run on OCP but I do not see any info that does point to a dedicated OCP cluster (if is dedicated is like a bare metal install and defy the purposes of a kubernetes cluster install).

Does anyone have experience on how is sas viya working in a kubernetes cluster and if does work on a shared cluster split by [projects/namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/).

Any help around it would help, this is not meant toward OCP only but any kubernetes flavor that does support multi app-platform deployments.

Comment: You're better off asking installation/admin questions on communities.sas.com

Comment: @Reeza, thank you, giving on both communities, hopping here are experts on this type of setup.